# CAS SSO 4.2.0 Database authentication setup error

Tags: java, spring, maven, cas

I tried to implement cas database authentication using war overlay method. But I ended up getting below error,

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'queryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/prabath/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/cas/WEB-INF/lib/cas-server-support-jdbc-4.2.0.jar!/org/jasig/cas/adaptors/jdbc/QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=queryEncodeDatabaseDataSource)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=queryEncodeDatabaseDataSource)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I first tried to setup basic cas and it worked. When I tried to add database auth only this happened.

My pom.xml is as follow,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.headstart.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-generic</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <cas.version>4.2.0</cas.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ja-sig</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ </url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And developerConfigContext.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
| deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
| all CAS deployers will need to modify.
|
| This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.
| The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring
| ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
| file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
|
| By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
| declaration to replace the default authentication handler with
| one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
+-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cas" p:username="root" p:password="adrTHbnm" />
    <util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
        <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
        <entry key-ref="primaryAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
    </util:map>
    <util:list id="authenticationMetadataPopulators">
        <ref bean="successfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator" />
        <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
    </util:list>
    <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.NamedStubPersonAttributeDao" p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />
    <alias name="personDirectoryPrincipalResolver" alias="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
        <entry>
            <key>
                <value>memberOf</value>
            </key>
            <list>
                <value>faculty</value>
                <value>staff</value>
                <value>org</value>
            </list>
        </entry>
    </util:map>
    <alias name="serviceThemeResolver" alias="themeResolver" />
    <alias name="jsonServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />
    <alias name="defaultTicketRegistry" alias="ticketRegistry" />
    <alias name="ticketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy" alias="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" />
    <alias name="multiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy" alias="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" />
    <alias name="anyAuthenticationPolicy" alias="authenticationPolicy" />
    <alias name="acceptAnyAuthenticationPolicyFactory" alias="authenticationPolicyFactory" />
    <bean id="auditTrailManager" class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager" p:entrySeparator="${cas.audit.singleline.separator:|}" p:useSingleLine="${cas.audit.singleline:false}" />
    <alias name="neverThrottle" alias="authenticationThrottle" />
    <util:list id="monitorsList">
        <ref bean="memoryMonitor" />
        <ref bean="sessionMonitor" />
    </util:list>
    <alias name="defaultPrincipalFactory" alias="principalFactory" />
    <alias name="defaultAuthenticationTransactionManager" alias="authenticationTransactionManager" />
    <alias name="defaultPrincipalElectionStrategy" alias="principalElectionStrategy" />
    <alias name="searchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
    <alias name="dataSource" alias="searchModeDatabaseDataSource" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I should use "**queryEncodeDatabaseDataSource**" if I am using "**QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler**". But here I am using "**SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler**".

I was able to resolve this issue by using **QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler**. Or just by adding "" to config. It seems no matter what authentication handler we define, cas automatically initializes QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler first.

Answer (score 0):

This is my deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



<bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  p:url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cas"
  p:username="root"
  p:password="*****" />

<util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
    <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
    <entry key-ref="primaryAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
</util:map>

<util:list id="authenticationMetadataPopulators">
    <ref bean="successfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator" />
    <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
</util:list>

<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.NamedStubPersonAttributeDao"
      p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />

<alias name="acceptUsersAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
<alias name="personDirectoryPrincipalResolver" alias="primaryPrincipalResolver" />

<util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
    <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
    <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
    <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
    <entry>
        <key><value>memberOf</value></key>
        <list>
            <value>faculty</value>
            <value>staff</value>
            <value>org</value>
        </list>
    </entry>
</util:map>

<alias name="serviceThemeResolver" alias="themeResolver" />

<alias name="jsonServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />

<alias name="defaultTicketRegistry" alias="ticketRegistry" />

<alias name="ticketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy" alias="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" />
<alias name="multiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy" alias="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" />

<alias name="anyAuthenticationPolicy" alias="authenticationPolicy" />
<alias name="acceptAnyAuthenticationPolicyFactory" alias="authenticationPolicyFactory" />

<bean id="auditTrailManager"
      class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"
      p:entrySeparator="${cas.audit.singleline.separator:|}"
      p:useSingleLine="${cas.audit.singleline:false}"/>

<alias name="neverThrottle" alias="authenticationThrottle" />

<util:list id="monitorsList">
    <ref bean="memoryMonitor" />
    <ref bean="sessionMonitor" />
</util:list>

<alias name="defaultPrincipalFactory" alias="principalFactory" />
<alias name="defaultAuthenticationTransactionManager" alias="authenticationTransactionManager" />
<alias name="defaultPrincipalElectionStrategy" alias="principalElectionStrategy" />



<alias name="queryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
<alias name="dataSource" alias="queryEncodeDatabaseDataSource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up here that I think this issue is in fact a bug that is fixed in 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line of code in your 'deployerConfigContext.xml':

`<alias   name="dataSource"   alias="queryEncodeDatabaseDataSource"/>`

Answer (score -1):

You're not following the docs. The alias must be queryEncodeDatabaseDataSource as the error tells you.